# Why doesn't "Bitcoin Wallet" app for Android transmit payment?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, payment, bitcoin-wallet-app

Why doesn't Bitcoin Wallet app transmit payment?

Bitcoin Wallet app no delivery transaction.

From the 18th of March to the date Bitcoin Wallet app retains my satoshis with the message **"this payment has not yet been transmitted"**; they invite you to make payment increases in the network fee in the order of 0.000288 satoshis, increments that I have paid 2 on the 18th and 2 plus on the 19th for a total payment increase to the network fee of 0.001152 satoshis, more than generous amount to call the attention of the miners (these increments do not record any address). The address generated by
Bitcoin Wallet app after receiving, and consulted in explorers as blockchain records that **"There are no transactions for this address"**. As additional data Bitcoin Wallet app received satoshis from paper wallet. As you can see it has taken more than prudential time to get any results. I don't know what may be happening in the menpool, I don't know who may
be responsible for this delay, I don't know who to complain to, I only have the community interested in Bitcoin continuing to be decentralized.  For this reason if someone can respond by clarifying what is happening with this deficient delay will be very welcome.
**In short**, use Bitcoin wallet app to receive a paper wallet, receipt accepted and generating new address, invite to increase the action network commission that is made several times, to date impossible to use the satoshis. Again community interested and knowledgeable to respond, **thank you very much**.

Comment: What software is this about? Bitcoin Core does not have any app.

Comment: This software is one more effort of the Bitcoin.org community to improve every day to be more disruptive.

You can also benefit from this technology, but without getting confused from the download page, pay close attention to the link: https://bitcoin.org ... wallet ... mobile

Comment: Are you talking about the Bitcoin Core software, or a mobile app listed on the bitcoin.org site?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. If I'm talking about a mobile application that appears on Bitcoin.org and specifically for smartphone with android OS.
For your interest thank you, in new post I will give information how this question was solved; thank you again.

Comment: That software has nothing to do with Bitcoin Core (which is a desktop application that implements a full node for the Bitcoin protocol). You'll need to clarify which app you're talking about, as there are dozens.

Comment: To close this thread and give it as solved.
The wallet object of these comments is the one that suggests the official page of Bitcoin.org. In this particular case it corresponds to the one used by a mobile phone with android operating system.
Solution: .- Make a security copy of the wallet.
               .- In the application go to settings then diagnostic and finally change string block.

Comment: Please answer my question. Bitcoin org is not an official site, it has a curated list of dozens of software implementations of the Bitcoin protocol; this question can't be answered without knowing what software you're talking about.

Comment: I edited the question to remove confusing references to *Bitcoin-core* (a completely different program).